# React, while routing, url changes but the ui updates only after page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a project that uses infinite scrolling to display the user information in the ui taken from an external API. I've managed to fetch the data successfully from the API and also apply the infinite scrolling methodology after a lot of googling.

Now, I'm trying to make a dynamical routing work, so basically, when the user clicks on the card containing the user information that I'm getting from the API, It should be able to redirect to its personal page where there's gonna be even more personal data. So, I'm using routing for that and I managed to do that as well.

In the `User.jsx` file, I got the personal information about one single user that I get from the API. Also, on this page, I also have a list of this single user's friends and when I click on those friend's card, I should be able to redirect to their own personal page. I've managed to do that in a way, the functionality works, but nothing changes in the ui unless if I refresh the page after clicking the friend's card, after that, page displays the user and their personal data correctly. So that's essentially what I'm trying to fix, when I click on the card of user's friend list, the url changes immediately from `localhost:3000/users/1` to `localhost:3000/users/2`, but the ui changes only after I refresh the page.

I'd appreciate any tips and help I can get, thank you in advance, here's the
**User.jsx**

```
 const params = useParams();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

// Getting the single user 
  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData(){
      const res = await axios(`http://sweeftdigital-intern.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/user/${params.id}`);
      console.log(res.data);
      setUsers(res.data);
    }
    fetchData()
  },[]);


// Getting the list of friends 
  const fetchData = (setItems, items) => {
    let url =  `http://sweeftdigital-intern.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/user/${params.id}/friends/1/20`;
    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        setItems([...items, ...res.data.list]);
        console.log(res);
      });
   };

// Browsing more friends by changing the page from API
  const moreData = () => {
    let url = `http://sweeftdigital-intern.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/user/${params.id}/friends/${page}/20`;
    
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      setItems([...items, ...res.data.list]);
      setPage(page+1)
      setIsFetching(false)
    });
  }

// infinite scrolling methodology

  const isScrolling =()=>{
    if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop!==document.documentElement.offsetHeight){
      return;
    }
    setIsFetching(true)
  }
 
useEffect(()=>{
   fetchData(setItems,items);
   window.addEventListener("scroll", isScrolling);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", isScrolling);
 },[]);


 useEffect(() => {
  if (isFetching){
    moreData();
  }
}, [isFetching]);

  if(!users) return <p>Fetching...</p>

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='container'>
        <img src={users.imageUrl}/>
        <h1 className='info'>Info</h1>
        <div className='card-div'>
          <div className='name-div'>
            <h3 style={{fontWeight:"bold", fontSize:"30px", color:"#FF416C"}}>{users.prefix} {users.name} {users.lastName}</h3>
            <h3 style={{fontStyle:"italic", fontSize:"22px"}}>{users.title}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className='details-div'>
            <h3>Email: {users.email}</h3>
            <h3>Ip Address: {users.ip}</h3>
            <h3>Job Area: {users.jobArea}</h3>
            <h3>Job Type: {users.jobType}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1 className='adress'>Address</h1>
        <div className='address-div'>
          <h3 style={{fontSize:"25px"}}>{users.company.name} {users.company.suffix}</h3>
          <div> 
            <h3>City: {users.address.city}</h3>
            <h3>Country: {users.address.country}</h3>
            <h3>State: {users.address.state}</h3>
            <h3>Street Address: {users.address.streetAddress}</h3>
            <h3>ZIP: {users.address.zipCode}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='friends-div'><h1 className='friends-h1'>Friends</h1></div>
      <div className="card-container">
      {items.map((user,key) => (
        <Card key={key} id={user.id} prefix={user.prefix} name={user.name} lastName={user.lastName} image={user.imageUrl} job={user.title}/>
       ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `params.id` to the `useEffect`'s dependency list in order to know when it should try to update the UI

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData(){
      const res = await axios(`http://sweeftdigital-intern.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/user/${params.id}`);
      console.log(res.data);
      setUsers(res.data);
    }
    fetchData()
  },[params.id]);
```

Comment: yes of course, thank you !